Google Chat bot will sometimes diplay an error, sometimes not, when running the same function
Our company is setting a Google Chat bot to help users with some tasks, like automated mails to HR when sick, setting calendar events when on holidays, etc. This bot is also required to call some external API's sometimes, for specific data requests.
Google App script functions behind the bot work fine, but sometimes, even on simple functions like adding a calendar event, the bot will just respond "Unable to process your request", while the function worked like a charm seconds before, and will work again seconds later.
For example, when requested to add a calendar event via a button click, out of 5 tries, 4 worked fine, and the fifth failed.
failure at 5th try
the logs say eveything is fine
When opening the logs, everything worked fine and the script went through all requested functions without an error. All variables were at the state they're supposed to, and the event was actually successfully created all the times the script was run (even the fifth execution).
Little bit of background, when chatting with the bot, the standard onMessage(event) function is called, checks what the user said, then depending on the inputs, answers a different card. The user then proceeds to fill the card and submit the results via a button. Which triggers the onCardClick(event) function, which, depending on the function called by this button, sends the input to some other functions. The Google App Script is linked to a Google Cloud project with Google Chat API enabled and configured correctly. When it fails, Google Cloud log explorer shows nothing, and so does the Google App Script logs.
The part of the script that's called (if that helps). Variables were checked and cleaned before being passed to the function.
function calevent(debut,fin,comm) {
  console.log('INFO - calevent - called');
  try {
  var event = CalendarApp.createAllDayEvent(comm,debut,fin);
  console.log('INFO - calevent - Event created, ID : ' + event.getId());
  var res = "J'ai bien créé votre événement !";
  }
  catch (error){
    var res = "ERREUR - L'événement n'a pas pu être créé.";
    console.log(error);
  }
  return {text:res};
}

Logs are fine, script is running correctly... i just don't get why the bot will sometimes display an error message when everything is fine in the background and runs like a charm 5 sec later.
Has anyone encountered this kind of behaviour on a Google Chat bot ?

You could make sure that debut and fin are both dates

Function works fine using slashes commands, problems only occurs when playing with cards and dialogs / responses.
What really gets me crazy is sometimes, when using cards and responding with simple plain text, the bot will display the answer, sometimes not... i'm so lost.
Again, linking the same functions to slashes commands run flawlessly, and the bot always displays the text response.

Well debut and fin should not be text.  They should both be javascript Date() objects anything short of that and you have problems

They are, as the "main" function calls calevent by passing this :
return calevent(new Date(debut_epoch),new Date(fin_epoch),comm);
